# Can I load a CKEditor plugin from the CDN?

Tags: ckeditor

I am loading CKEditor from its CDN, called with

```html
<script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.6.0/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

and

```js
CKEDITOR.replace("Content", {"customConfig":"\/public\/javascripts\/ckeditor.config.js"})
```

I want to use the [Justify](http://ckeditor.com/addon/justify) plugin. The [CKEditor CDN Guidelines](https://cdn.ckeditor.com/) explain how to use custom, self-hosted plugins, but say nothing about how to use standard plugins. Do I have to download the Justify plugin (and any other plugins I may want) and host it myself, or is there some way of including it from the CDN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must switch to the `standard-all` version and then just add in `extraPlugins` whatever you want as long as it's a plugin from CKSource.

Comment: Please give sample